# Consequence of having no triangles in a line graph G?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to recall a theorem/general statement that relates the number of triangles in a line graph G=L(H) to the degrees of vertices in H. I have been told that if there are no triangles in G (such as $G=K_{3,2}$) then all vertices in H must have degree 1 or 2.

I am struggling to see why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Could the statement you encountered be about line graphs of triangle free graphs?

Let the propositions $p$ and $q$ be
$p:$ $H$ is a triangle-free graph such that $ \forall v \in V(H) deg(v) \leq2$
$q:$ $G = L(H)$ is triangle-free.

You're asking for a proof of $q \Rightarrow p$

We'll go a step ahead and prove $p \Leftrightarrow q$

Backward proof  $q \Rightarrow p$. We'll prove by contrapositive $ \neg p => \neg q $

We are given that $\exists\ v \in V(H)\land  deg(v) \geq 3$. Then the vertex would look something like "A" in the drawing where the other vertices may have any neighbors and "A" may have more neighbors.

[image]

Consider the corresponding line graph, looking at the edges $AB, AC, AD$ we can say $\left\{\{AB, AC\}, \{AC, AD\}, \{AD, AB\}\right\} \subseteq E(L(H)) $, thus we have a triangle on $AB, AC, AD$ in $G$, Q.E.D.

Now for forward proof $p \Rightarrow q$, again by proof of the contrapositive $ \neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$

$\exists$ a triangle in the line graph. We argue that it would be of the type $AB, BC, CA$ or $AB, AC, AD$ in $G$ and thus imply existence of either a triangle in $H$ or a vertex with degree 3 in $H$. Since we know $H$ is triangle-free it implies there must be a vertex with degree 3 in $H$. Q.E.D.